# Won't the test charge disturb the electric field to be measured?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

As written in **Principles of Physics** by Halliday, Resnick and Walker:

> The electric field is a *vector field*; it consists of a distribution of vectors,one for each point in the region around a charged object. In principle, we can define the electric field at some point near the charged object. We first place a positive charge $q_0$, called a **test charge**,at the point. We then measure electrostatic force $\vec{F}$ that acts on the test charge. Finally, we define the electric field $\vec{E}$ at that point due to the charged object as $$\vec{E} = \frac{\vec{F}}{q_0}$$ .

So, this is the way they derive the electric field. But one thing that perplexes me is that as test charge has its own field, so when the test charge is introduced in the field of concerned charged object, say another point charge $+q$ , won't it get shifted due to the repulsion from the test charge $q_0$ (which is, by convention, positive)? Then consequently the field of $+q$ will also be shifted. In a word, it will get disturbed by that test charge. But the book derived the formula as if the positive point charge $+q$ remained fixed i.e. the test charge had no effect on the field of the point charge. But how can it be? If the test charge $q_0$ is a charge, then obviously it has also field which will exert force on $+q$. So how can the formula be true? Why did the book neglect this?

This phenomenon can be compared to earth's gravitational field. When a body moves upward, it exerts force on the earth downward. But as the earth has huge mass, its shifting can be neglected and hence it doesn't affect its gravitational field.

But here it is a point positive charge; it has no huge mass. So why did the book neglect its shifting and how can the formula be true? Please help.

Comment: The sign of the test charge doesn't matter for the definition of the electric field. Using a negative charge flips the force but when it's divided by the test charge it flips back to the right direction. The positive test charge, however,  is useful when interpreting the field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The presence of the test particle may influence the distribution of charge in the charged object. The electric field measured the above way then depends on the quantity of charge in the test particle and is different from what it is when the test particle is removed.

If the charge of the test particle is much lower than the charge of the charged object, this influence becomes weak and the difference negligible.

Comment: So Is there no way of finding the "exact" Electric field due a particular distribution? Can't I provide a force that holds the distribution perfectly @Ján Lalinský

Comment: No measurement of real number is exact. Length, time measurements always have some expected error. Electric field too.

Answer (score 3):

The definition of Electric Field is:

> The electric field at a point is defined as the limit of the ratio between the force on a test charge placed at that point to the test charge **as the test charge approaches to zero**.

So in the definition, we have seen that the placed test charge is vary small and hence the effect of this charge on the field is also very small. This small effect of test charge on the field may be neglected. $$\vec{E} (\vec{r}) = \lim_{q \to 0} (\frac{\vec{F}}{q})$$ .

Comment: Thanks . You have answered to the point. The test charge must have negligible charge. The book didn't mention that. Can you prescribe me any good physics book??

Comment: The limit is not necessary since the charge will cancel out. You would get the same result regardless of what value of test charge is used.

Comment: @Asaf: The point is that the electric field you're measuring is produced by another distribution of charge, and placing a test charge will disturb that distribution. That's why we need a small test charge.

Comment: By 'disturb' do you mean that it will move the other charges?

Comment: @Asaf: Yes, that's the idea.

Comment: It seems that Jackson's Electrodynamics agrees with you about taking the limit. However, I still think it is unnecessary since one defines the electric field for a fixed position and time so movement doesn't play a role. I agree that from the experimental point of view it makes sense to use an arbitrarily small charge to measure the field, but this is just to better approximate the situation of measuring at a fixed time.

Comment: @Asaf: No, you don't get the same answer regardless of the size of the test charge, for the reasons described in the question.

Comment: Jan Lalinsky's answer (test charge small compared to the other charges) is actually better than using a limit as a definition. The limit is somewhat meaningless, since charge is quantized.

Comment: Actually I flow D.Chattopadhyay, P.C.Rakshit's book on 'ELECTRICITY AND MAGNETISM'. You may read it.@user36790

Answer (score 0):

It is called the electrostatic field because all the movement of the charges and time dependence has been ignored, hence static.

On the other hand, when you place two charges $q_0$ and $+q$ they will both indeed create a field. However, what you measure is the **force** acting on $q_0$ and since a charge is not affected by it's own field then this wouldn't be counted in $\vec{E}$.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, which has to do with the rearrangement of the other charges due to the introduction of the test charge.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the superposition principle,there is no movement of the test charge.And also there is no need of using the limit to define the electrostatic field.