# What is the meaning when we say something is at the higher potential and the other is at lower and wht is the direction of flow of charge?

Tags: electrostatics

Electric potential is defined as the work done in bringing per unit positive charge from infinity to a point in the electric field of some other charge.
 let me explain what i actually want to ask.
consider a battery [image]

as the two electrodes are connected electrons start to flow from the right part towards the left.since electrons are moving the right part is at higher potential and the left at lower.but what actually does we mean by potential at right part and at the left one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Won't the test charge disturb the electric field to be measured?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/145135/)

Comment: I've suggested a question that addresses what I think you're asking about. The definition of potential you describe requires an infinitesimally small *test charge* so it does  not perturb the field you are measuring. For real systems yes introducing a finite test charge will change the system and the potential you actually measure will be different from the potential measured with a test charge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One useful analogy is to imagine the wire as a channel down a hillside. Water from the top of the hill flows down the channel to the bottom. You need a pump to get the water back up the hill to the top.

The water is analogous to the electricity or flow of electrons. The pump is the battery. The hill is the potential difference.

The water moves from the higher end of the channel to the lower. Similarly the electricity flows from the "higher" (in terms of electrical potential) end of the wire to the "lower".